# How to get foreign key table values using foreign key in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

These are my domain models, I created a view using this SubCategory model. I need to show a table in the view which consist of headings (CategoryName, SubCategoryName).

How can I access `CategoryName` values respect to the each rows in the `SubCategory` Table?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your data selection look? Show us some of the code in the view also

Comment: What have you done to try and get the data. You will need a join to get the Category name and in linq, that is the `include` clause. Show what code you trying to use and maybe i can help if it doesn't work.

Comment: @GidiBloke Thanks brother, I went through some tutorials on eager loading and found out which is same as ur answer, thanks for the help boys. :)